# Exceptions / Try-Catch - Making sure user input is strictly a double & not only an int

Tags: java, validation, exception, try-catch, wrapper

I'm wondering if there is a way that I can make my code stricter with regard to user input?

I'm trying Exceptions / Try-Catch Blocks, and have to accept some user input and validate that it is the correct date type.

Is there a way that I can make the user input a strict double? i.e. I don't want the user to be able to input a value without a decimal point e.g. an int like 5 & have it be validated and converted to double, returning 5.0 - I want the user to be prompted to enter a double value strictly, making sure that a decimal point is part of the value entered.

Would using Wrappers or something like this be appropriate, and if so - how could I do this?

Current Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class InputExceptions {

    //Do we have to do any Wrapping / instanceOf Double ?
    //Can we accept an integer (no decimal point) for double entry ?

    private static int inputInt;
    private static double inputDouble;

    public static int inputInt() {

        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean inputOK = false;
        while (inputOK == false) {
            System.out.println("*** Please Enter an Integer Value: ");
            try {
                inputInt = kybd.nextInt();
                kybd.nextLine();
                inputOK = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("*** ERROR: VALUE ENTERED NOT INTEGER ***");
                kybd.next();
            }
        }
        return inputInt;
    }

    public static double inputDouble() {
        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean inputOK = false;
        while (inputOK == false) {
            System.out.println("*** Please Enter a Double Value: ");
            try {
                inputDouble = kybd.nextDouble();
             kybd.nextLine();
                inputOK = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("*** ERROR: VALUE ENTERED NOT DOUBLE ***");
                kybd.next();
            }
        }
        return inputDouble;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*** INTEGER Input: " + inputInt() + " ***");
        System.out.println("*** DOUBLE Input: " + inputDouble() + " ***");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why can't you use the exception block that you already have? `nextDouble` is doing the validation.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

As is, if I input a non-decimal value e.g. 12 - then I get 12.0 returned. I'm wanting to make it reject an int input e.g. 12 - & instead only accept a double input e.g. 12.0

I'm wondering if there is a way to make the code strict as desired?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the number as a String and check it contains a '.' character.  This can be parsed with Double.parseDouble(String).  Of course you can still enter `1.0` and is the same as entering `1.` or `1`

Comment: Do You know if it would be possible to get it to do what I want it to do using the Wrapper / instanceOf technique?

Comment: @user2904978 what do you mean by "using the Wrapper / instanceOf technique"? please give an example.

Comment: -1 as this answer assumes that the dot (".") is the radix character. That doesn't hold for all possible locales.

Comment: What I mean is checking if an object reference is to a specific Class e.g something like : if ( obj instanceOf Double) - where a primitive data type of double has been cast to primitive wrapper type Double?



I'm dealing with some new concepts and I'm not sure if

Comment: e.g.

double n = 20.0;

Double obj = new Double(n);

Comment: What I mean is checking if an object reference is to a specific Class e.g something like : if ( obj instanceOf Double) - where a primitive data type of double has been cast to primitive wrapper type Double? I'm dealing with some new concepts and I'm not sure if I'm understanding the manner in which things can be implemented.

e.g. double n = 20.0; Double obj = new Double(n);

Comment: @user2904978 It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve as I don't see how objects relate to validating text entered.

Comment: @Isaac You are more than welcome to improve my answer or add your own answer.